# How can I make a request to multiple URLs and parse the results from each page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cheerio

I'm using the popular npm package cheerio with request to retrieve some table data.

Whilst I can retrieve and parse the table from a single page easily, I'd like to loop over / process multiple pages.

I have tried wrapping inside loops / various utilities offers by the `async` package but can't figure this one out. In most cases, node runs out of memory.

current code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require("axios");


var url = someUrl;

const getData = async url => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const data = response.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const announcement = $(`#someId`).each(function(i, elm) {
      console.log($(this).text()) 
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};


getData(url); //<--- Would like to give an array here to fetch from multiple urls /  pages
```

My current approach, after trying loops, is to wrap this inside another function with a callback param. However no success yet and is getting quite messy.

What is the best way to feed an array to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do them  one at a time:

```
; (async() => {
  for(let url of urls){
    await getData(url)
  }
})()
```

Comment: Perfect thank you @pguardiario - Elegantly simple and exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Promise.all` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

For loops are usually a bad idea when dealing with asynchronous calls. It depends how many calls you want to make but I believe this could be enough. I would use an array of promises that fetch the data and map over the results to do the parsing.

Comment: Thank you @hinosxz was good to re-review this documentation and game a few more angles to try 